# multidimensional array - adding a key and value where a key and value is matched

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm trying to add a key and value (associative) from an array to another array, where one specific key and value match. Here are the two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(
            1 => array(
                'walgreens' => 'location',
                'apples' => 'product1',
                'oranges' => 'product2'
            ),
            2 => array(
                'walmart' => 'location',
                'apples' => 'product1',
                'oranges' => 'product2',
                'milk' => 'product3'
            )
       );
$array2 = array(
            1 => array(
                'walgreens' => 'location',
                'apples' => 'product1',
                'oranges' => 'product2',
                'bananas' => 'product3',
            )
      );
```

Here is the attempt I made at modifying `$array1` to have key 'bananas' and value 'product3':

```
$dataCJ = getCJItem($isbn);
         foreach ($array1 as $subKey => $subArray) {
            foreach($subArray as $dkey => $dval){
                foreach($array2 as $cjk => $cjv){
                    foreach($cjv as $cjkey => $cjval){
                         if($dval['walgreens'] == $cjval['walgreens']){
                              $dval['bananas'] = $cjval['bananas'];
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

This doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: What output do you want for your input example?

Comment: Hard to workout without output format required..

Answer (score 3):

Change `=> $dval` to `=> &$dval`.  Currently you are creating and writing to a new variable and the update will not work in-place.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Helped me so much!!

Answer (score 2):

I would look at `array_merge()` function!

Here is a [start with the PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php).

---

For your specific case, you could do the following :

```
foreach($array1 as $key1 => $values1){
    foreach($array2 as $key2 => $values2){
        if($values1[0] == $values2[0]){
            $array1[$key1] = array_merge($values1, $values2);
        }
    }
}
```

Note to simplify the problem you should inverse the first key=> value pair of the array.

Having an array this way would be a lot simper :

```
array(
    'location' => "The location (eg:walgreens)",
    //...
);
```

This way you could change the comparison to the following instead :

```
$values1['location'] == $values2['location']
```

Which would be safer in the case the array is not built with the location as the first pair.